# How to set the default language in Notepad++ for Rails View files

Tags: notepad++, ruby, ruby-on-rails, syntax

Similar question to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/58672/how-to-set-the-default-language-in-notepad?s=5375312c-0247-407f-ac78-ad54dafc20a3) but my question goes a step further.

I'm developing in rails and would like Notepad++ to automatically use html formatting on files with the extension html.erb. For example 'hello.html.erb' should open with html syntax highlighting.

How do I accomplish this?

Note(1): I've linked to a question which shows how to set default languages. But the solution doesn't work for extensions with dot separators, such as 'html.erb'

Note(2): I'm avoiding simply using html formatting for .erb extensions because I want those to use ruby syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

I've went browsing in the Notepad++ source code, and it seems that the double extension case is not handled.

The function that determines the automatic loading of language is "Buffer::setFileName" (in Buffer.cpp). That function looks up the extension by stopping at the **first** dot encountered by starting in last position since it uses Microsoft's "[PathFindExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" function.