# when i open new file it insert code in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, assembly

First  i want to tell you that i now i only use notepad++ for assembly language.
and i have made assembly my default language by reading this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/58672/how-to-set-the-default-language-in-notepad) so when i open new file it highlight as assembly now its possible when i open new file it open with some code??
as when i open new file it open with

```
.model small
.stack 100H
.data
.code
 main proc


 main endp
 end main
```

Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: Possible duplicate on StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749747/notepad-premade-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++ seems hasn't support for new files with a content. Try SynWrite editor, also free. You can put Asm file to `template\newdoc` subfolder and call `File>New` menu with it. (See help topic about new file template)